# Filtering/Visualising JMX fields

Tags: logstash, kibana

I am successfully able to integrate JMX plugin for logstash. Now to i am trying to Visualize the JMX data.

For this i am trying to add custom fields to the parsed jmx data.

Example:

```
input{
    beats{
      port => 27080
      congestion_threshold => 1500
    }
    jmx {
      path => "file://Machine01/Users/username/projects/Logstash/logstash/bin/jmx"
      polling_frequency => 15
      type => "jmx"
      nb_thread => 4
 }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "Type1"{
        grok{
          break_on_match => false
          patterns_dir => ["C:\Users\users\projects\Logstash\logstash\bin\patterns"]
          match => { "message" => "%{YEAR:Year}%{MONTHNUM:Month}%{MONTHDAY:Day} %{HOUR:Hour}%{MINUTE:Minute}%{SECOND:Second} %{LogLevel:LogVerbosity} %{MODULE:MODULENAME}%{SPACE}%{MESSAGEID:MESSAGEID} %{SUBMODULE:SUBMODULE} %{MESSAGE:MESSAGE}"}
          add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
          add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
          add_tag => ["Groked"]
        }

      if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
                  drop { }
        }

   if [type] == "jmx" {
   if ("OperatingSystem.ProcessCpuLoad" in [metric_path] or "OperatingSystem.SystemCpuLoad" in [metric_path]) {
     ruby {
     code => "event['cpuLoad'] = event['metric_value_number'] * 100"
     add_tag => [ "cpuLoad" ]
     } 
   }
 }
  }
}
output {  
    if [type] == "jmx" {
        elasticsearch {  
            hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]  
            index => "jmx"   
        }
    } else {
        elasticsearch {  
            hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"] 
            manage_template => true
            index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
        }
    }
}
```

But, In KIbana it is not displaying any such newly added field, this is the data i am getting in Kibana.

```
@version:1 
@timestamp:May 30th 2016, 18:50:36.622 
host:host 
path:file://Machine01/Users/username/projects/Logstash/logstash/bin/jmx 
type:jmx 
metric_path:OperatingSystem.ProcessCpuLoad 
metric_value_number:0.003 
_id:AVUB0r_4sUXN-4lFtxGq 
_type:jmx
_index:jmx _score:
```

How can i change this to add new field which i have defined in the filter.

Also, is there any better way to visualise JMX data on Kibana.

Comment: You probably need to show us your full Logstash config, at least the inputs and the other upstream filters.

Comment: @Val , added the full config

Comment: can you share the jmx json conf?